# Converting sql query to linq new in linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

As i am new to linq can you please help me converting below sql query to linq.

```
Select o.* from [Order] o Left Join TransactionsTable yo on o.Id = yo.OrderId                           
Where yo.OrderId is null and Convert(date,o.CreatedOnUtc) = 
Convert(date,getutcdate()) and  o.OrderStatusId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var q = from o in Orders
         join yo in TransactionsTables on o.Id equals yo.OrderId into tt
         from yo in tt.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where !yo.OrderId.HasValue 
          && o.CreatedOnUtc.Value.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date
          && o.OrderStatusId == 1
       select o ;
```